# Приостановка выполнения по любому Exception'у

Tags: отладка, eclipse

Знаю, что можно сделать через добавление в список Breakpoints, но там почти каждый класс надо добавлять, к тому же если отметить что-то, то начинается приостановка во внешних библиотеках, исходного кода которого у меня нету.
Как сделать была приостановка при любом exception'e, для строки которого есть исходный код в проекте?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте через `Run > Add Java Exception Breakpoint`

Comment: Это как раз то, о чём я говорил: "через добавление в список Breakpoints"
Самая главная проблема, это то, что вылезают ошибки из внешних библиотек, это жутко мешает отладке.

Comment: Неужели все так и мучаются? Как вообще работать?